# ParallelProcess blocks indefinitely for Task.WaitAll randomly , processes fine most of the time

Tags: c#, wcf, parallel-processing

I have a process that runs periodically every 5 mins. It picks up some records from the db  and calls code to Register,  in parallel 25 tasks are called, waits for execution of all those parallel tasks to complete and then continues processing the remaining 25 tasks at a time. It runs fine most of the times  but after a few weeks or sometimes even a few days , it will just hang. It most likely is hung at wait all where one of the tasks has not completed.

We have not been able to reproduce this in a local environment or even in our test environment in a load scenario. It is a WCF application so the Register method is a service call and we are not sure if a particular call of register task is not returning , then why it isn't - there is no database error or deadlock detected,  all queries that execute in that task have a timeout of 30 secs. When it halts and we kill the service , and restart then the same record executes without any issues.

====Snippet of code that executes the 25 tasks at a time -

```
public void RegisterApplications()
{
throttleCount = 25;
IList<OnlineApplication> onlineApplications =  VDService.GetOnlineApplicationsPendingRegistration());
countTotal = onlineApplications.Count;
  foreach (OnlineApplication onlineApplication in onlineApplications)
       {
          object parameters = new StartRegistrationParameters()
                        {
                            Application = onlineApplication,
                            Context = Context.CurrentOperationContext
                        };
                        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(StartRegisterApplication, parameters);
                        registrationTasks.Add(task);
                        onlineApplicationTasks.Add(task.Id, (long)onlineApplication.OnlineApplicationId);
                        counterTasksForThrottling++;
                  if (counterTasksForThrottling >= throttleCount)
                        {
                            countProcessed += CountTasksCompleted(registrationTasks, messageLog, onlineApplicationTasks);
                            counterTasksForThrottling = 0;

                            // initialize again.
                            registrationTasks.RemoveAll(t => t.Id > 0);
                        }

        }

countProcessed += CountTasksCompleted(registrationTasks, messageLog, onlineApplicationTasks);
}
```

==========Count Task Completed Method ===============

```
    private int CountTasksCompleted(List<Task> registrationTasks, StringBuilder messageLog, Dictionary<int, long> onlineApplicationTasks)
    {
        int countTasksCompleted = 0;

        try
        {
            if (messageLog == null)
            {
                messageLog = new StringBuilder();
            }
            if (registrationTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                Task.WaitAll(registrationTasks.ToArray(),);
            }
        }
        // catching this exception as it is thrown after all the tasks have completed and  when any one of the  tasks within throw an error. 
        // the task status in the task show us which have completed and which have faulted after this.
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (registrationTasks != null && registrationTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                countTasksCompleted = registrationTasks.Where(task => task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).Count();
                var failedtasks = registrationTasks.Where(task => task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).ToList();
                foreach (Task failedTask in failedtasks)
                {
                    messageLog.AppendFormat("Id {0},", onlineApplicationTasks[failedTask.Id]);
                }
            }
        }
        return countTasksCompleted;
    }
```

Comment: That sounds very much like a Race Condition and those are a pain to debug. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: If you can't find the race condition, it may be more pragmatic to modify the solution to be fault tolerant (i.e. if you kill the process it doesn't leave data in an invalid or corrupt state) and redundancy-friendly (i.e. you can run more than one process at a time without fear of double-processing). Then run multiple copies of the process and schedule them to be reset every day at a certain time, e.g. by [scheduling an app pool recycle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart/). Not pretty but sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds very much like a [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and those are a pain to debug. If that really is the case, there is little we can help you with other then point out any potential causes of race conditions we can spot - but there is likely more in the rest of it.

Your description does make it sound like this might be a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) case. While you say you detected non with the DB access, if your code or the code you are using uses any form of [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement), these can still happen.

As a start, add some more loging to the mix. For every disticnt step, add a "I am at step X" to the log. This will help you nail down the exact cause.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for the response, I don't have any lock  statements in my code that is executing. I have added some logging and since its occurs in production it has been a painful process to wait for a release, It has not really given me any clues, also it  occurs so randomly with no pattern , it has been difficult to trace down the cause.  A race condition would cause  a  data issue , but would it cause a task to just halt and not process ( without any traces like a deadlock in the db)?

Comment: @Yogi I go by the book definition of race condition. "A race condition or race hazard is the behavior of an electronics, software, or other system where the system's substantive behavior is dependent on the sequence or timing of other uncontrollable events." It is clearly a timing thing, because it only happens rarely under productive load. And not halting is what I would call 'substantive behavior' :D

Comment: @Yogi For example: One part is trying to gather 25 threads, counting up while doing so. The other part is only accepting a collecting of 25 threads, nothing less or more. Or maybe even counting down from 25 to 0. If there is a update race condition while building the list or working off the list, you end up with too many or to few Elements.

Comment: And when you deal with lists, you can run into what I call the "Index Race Conditon". If one code finds you need to work with element 10 but then any element of 1-9 is removed, the whole number just got invalid. I think that tis the reason why there *are* no concurrent lists. Bags and Dictionaries do not suffer those issues, so they do appear in concurrent variants.